# OpenCSV - Convert List<String[]> to List<Integer> list?

Tags: java, rest, csv, export-to-csv, opencsv

Is it possible to convert List String[] to ListInteger list?

I'm creating a program and I need some way of converting the CSV to int so I can sum it up.

```
@Path("/values")
public class values {

int totalSum = 0;
int value = 0;

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public int getSum() throws IOException {
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"));
    List<String[]> read = reader.readAll();
    //need to convert List<String[]> to List<Integer> list
    return sum.sum(list, totalSum);
}

@POST
public String addValue() throws IOException {
    String valueString = Integer.toString(value);
    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("yourfile.csv"), ',');
    String[] entries = valueString.split(",");
    writer.writeNext(entries);
    writer.close();
    return "ok";  
}  

@DELETE
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String deleteList() {
    list.clear();
    return "ok";
}

}
```

sum.java

```
@Path("/values/sum")
public class sum {

public static int sum(List<Integer> list, int totalSum) {
    for(int i : list) {
          totalSum += i;
          }
    return totalSum;
}

}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>PACKAGENAME</display-name>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
     <!-- Register resources and providers under com.vogella.jersey.first package. -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>PACKAGENAME</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Perhaps there is a better way to go about this? I am implementing CSV as a way of maintaining data each time I perform GET.

Comment: Tried in your `sum()` just using `Integer.valueOf(String)`? Then it can take a `List<String>`, looks like it'd take a bit more work than just that since it's a `List<String[]>`, but that'd probably be your best bet either way.

Answer (score 0):

using java8 stream API directly the sum of all:

```
private static int sum(List<String[]> stringArrayList){
    return stringArrayList.stream().flatMap(l -> Arrays.stream(l))
            .mapToInt(str -> Integer.valueOf(str)).sum();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<String[]> stringArrayList = Lists.newArrayListWithCapacity(2);
    String[] sArray1 = { "1", "5" };
    stringArrayList.add(sArray1);
    String[] sArray2 = { "53", "49" };
    stringArrayList.add(sArray2);

    System.out.println(sum(stringArrayList));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int sum(List<String[]> source, int totalSum)
{
    for(String[] arr: source)
    {
        for(String s: arr) totalSum += Integer.valueOf(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Appears to work with no errors being thrown. Do you have experience with OpenCSV by chance? I have no idea where the CSV is being created.

Comment: That's just straight java logic, not OpenCSV logic. Not familiar with OpenCSV.

Answer (score 0):

You have string of array which you can parse it into int via iterating each element of the array:

```
String[] entries = valueString.split(",");
long sum = 0;

for(String entry : entries)
{
    sum += Long.parseLong(entry.trim());
}
```

I used long instead of int because sometimes it happens that sum of integer field cross the integer type limit. So, take long for safer side.

Don't forget to use trim to remove white space from the value otherwise java will throw the NumberFormatException.

Assumption: All elements of string array contains integer value otherwise it will throws an exception.